# Rails method is returning a span tag instead of a string for my placeholder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a translation method that takes a string and returns another based on the user. It returns the string for all of my buttons and links but keeps returning a span tag when I try to use it with placeholders. I'm also using Twitter Bootstrap, not sure if that matters.

The translation method:

```
  def translator(english)
    # takes string and searches Translation.all for a match unless user.english
    unless current_user.english
      spanish = Translation.where(english: english)
    end
    return spanish.present? ? spanish.last.spanish : english
  end
```

My search bar with the placeholder:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => "get" do %>
    <div class="input-group">
        <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query],
            placeholder: translate("Search"), class: "form-control" %>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
<% end %>
```

The tag being produced. It's saying translation missing even when I know there's a match. From view-source:

```
placeholder="<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.Search">Search</span>"
```

Comment: Why do you think that `translate` in the view will call the `translator` method in the helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a method called `translator` but you're calling a method called `translate`: you're calling the rails [translate helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate) instead of the one you've defined.

Comment: That was it. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!